# Ubuntu or Kali dowloads for VM

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I just installed Virtual BOX to run linux labs. I am running into the issue, when I download Ubuntu or Kali .ISO or .OVA file extensions these files appear as if they were PDF files - so VM does not recognize them. Any suggestions towards correcting this scenario is appreciated.

[View of a .OVA download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk7f4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about .ova files but you can try downloading the Ubuntu ISO file from [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2.0/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso).

Also, are you correctly using the ISO file in Virtual box by going to the VM -> Settings -> Storage and then clicking on the disk icon besides controller, that should open the file explorer and give you the option to add the ISO file.

Comment: I was missing a step as you pointed. Trying to get used to VM from VMWare which is a big change. Than you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't use comments just yet, (which is where I think this should be) however, if you're using windows 10, there's *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, or WSL for short. Its extremely simple to install and may be able to accomplish your needs. Lots of great features if you have the latest dev build of windows 10 like reading ext4 filesystem's and making them available to windows.

As for the original issue, I'm not sure I 100% understand what you mean by opening them as PDFs, but it sounds like maybe its a matter of changing the default program for those file extensions in your windows settings.  Have you tried **right click->open with** on the files in question ?

Had not seen the picture at first... Yes this is a default program issue. You can do as I suggested with right click, or go to **settings->Apps->default Apps->choose default apps by file type**

Comment: Thank you much for pointing the the fix, and for the tip on WSL. I will be installing it. Appreciated.